# adding the Animate.css library to my document?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im working through freecodecamp and during the jQuery section they tell you..

"we've already included both the jQuery library and the Animate.css library in the background so that you can use them in the editor."

So far i have been completing the exercises then jumping into notepad++ and experimenting with the code until i feel confident with what im doing.

I have added to the  of my document on notepad++

```
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

and

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
```

and outside the  i have

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("button").addClass("animated bounce");

});
</script>
```

have i added the jQuery & Animate.css library's correctly? 
the buttons i created are not bouncing where as they are in freecodecamp
console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have copied this code then the path to CSS file is probably not correct. You are accessing it from your local file system. You need to give complete path to actual file.
Here, you can use CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this its working fine in my snippet. Did you miss jQuery `class` or something like that? if you are using the `class` you should use `.yourclass` if its ID then `#yourclass` in jQuery. So check your code.Ty

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("button").addClass("animated bounce");

});
```

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.css">

<button>HI its me</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```